# Leaving values blank if not passed in str.format

Tags: python, string-formatting, missing-data

I've run into a fairly simple issue that I can't come up with an elegant solution for.

I'm creating a string using `str.format` in a function that is passed in a `dict` of substitutions to use for the format. I want to create the string and format it with the values if they're passed and leave them blank otherwise.

Ex

```
kwargs = {"name": "mark"}
"My name is {name} and I'm really {adjective}.".format(**kwargs)
```

should return

```
"My name is mark and I'm really ."
```

instead of throwing a `KeyError` (Which is what would happen if we don't do anything).

Embarrassingly, I can't even come up with an inelegant solution for this problem. I guess I could solve this by just not using `str.format`, but I'd rather use the built-in (which mostly does what I want) if possible.

Note: I don't know in advance what keys will be used. I'm trying to fail gracefully if someone includes a key but doesn't put it in the kwargs dict. If I knew with 100% accuracy what keys would be looked up, I'd just populate all of them and be done with it.

Comment: You can also use `str.format_map()` as described in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17215533/877069).

Comment: haha, "Embarrassingly, I can't even come up with an inelegant solution for this problem." You've just got dig deeper into inelegance!

Comment: **See also:** https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20248355/how-to-get-python-to-gracefully-format-none-and-non-existing-fields

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You can follow the recommendation in [PEP 3101](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3101/) and use a subclass Formatter:

```
import string

class BlankFormatter(string.Formatter):
    def __init__(self, default=''):
        self.default=default

    def get_value(self, key, args, kwds):
        if isinstance(key, str):
            return kwds.get(key, self.default)
        else:
            return string.Formatter.get_value(key, args, kwds)

kwargs = {"name": "mark", "adj": "mad"}     
fmt=BlankFormatter()
print fmt.format("My name is {name} and I'm really {adj}.", **kwargs)
# My name is mark and I'm really mad.
print fmt.format("My name is {name} and I'm really {adjective}.", **kwargs)
# My name is mark and I'm really .
```

---

As of Python 3.2, you can use [.format_map](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.format_map) as an alternative:

```
class Default(dict):
    def __missing__(self, key):
        return '{'+key+'}'

kwargs = {"name": "mark"}

print("My name is {name} and I'm really {adjective}.".format_map(Default(kwargs)))
```

which prints:

```
My name is mark and I'm really {adjective}.
```

Comment: Hmm. This is interesting. I think I'll actually go this route. I'm still not a fan of the ugly indexing that the other answer uses. Thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: I am a bit confused. Shouldn't `Formatter` be `string.Formatter`? Can that `else` part even be reached?

Comment: @EliasZamaria: Yes, it should have been `return string.Formatter` and that has been corrected. The `else` is reached if you use tuple indexing formatting like `"one {0} two {1}".format(1,2)` instead of keyword access. Thanks for the comment. Three year old bug fixed!

Answer (score 15):

Here is one option which uses [`collections.defaultdict`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict):

```
>>> from collections import defaultdict
>>> kwargs = {"name": "mark"}
>>> template = "My name is {0[name]} and I'm really {0[adjective]}."
>>> template.format(defaultdict(str, kwargs))
"My name is mark and I'm really ."
```

Note that we aren't using `**` to unpack the dictionary into keyword arguments anymore, and the format specifier uses `{0[name]}` and `{0[adjective]}`, which indicates that we should perform a key lookup on the first argument to `format()` using `"name"` and `"adjective"` respectively.  By using `defaultdict` a missing key will result in an empty string instead of raising a KeyError.

Comment: The indexing solution isn't (aesthetically) pretty, but you're right, it works as I want.

Comment: This is the simplest solution that I've found. It can also be a one-liner: "My name is {0[name]} and I'm really {0[adjective]}.".format(defaultdict(str, kwargs))  Beautiful!

Answer (score 0):

For the record:

```py
s = "My name is {name} and I'm really {adjective}."
kwargs = dict((x[1], '') for x in s._formatter_parser())
# Now we have: `kwargs = {'name':'', 'adjective':''}`.
kwargs.update(name='mark')
print s.format(**kwargs)  # My name is mark and I'm really .
```

Answer (score 0):

Wanted to add a pretty simple solution to the substituting any default values needed.

```
import string

class SafeDict(dict):
    def __init__(self, missing='#', empty='', *args, **kwargs):
        super(SafeDict, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.missing = missing
        self.empty = empty
    def __getitem__(self, item):
        return super(SafeDict, self).__getitem__(item) or self.empty
    def __missing__(self, key):
        return self.missing

values = SafeDict(a=None, c=1})
string.Formatter().vformat('{a} {c} {d}', (), values)
# ' 1 #'
```

Answer (score 0):

While subclassing a `Formatter` is probably the "right" answer, it is also possible to follow Python's strong ask-for-forgiveness-not-permission vein by catching the `KeyError`. The advantage of this approach is that it is easily flexible: In particular, it is easy to have "default" values which are not static (i.e., just a possibly blank constant) but can depend on the name of the key, such as here:

```py
def f(s, **kwargs):
    """Replaces missing keys with a pattern."""
    RET = "{{{}}}"
    try:
        return s.format(**kwargs)
    except KeyError as e:
        keyname = e.args[0]
        return f(s, **{ keyname: RET.format(keyname) }, **kwargs)
```

which will work in the following way:

```py
In [1]: f("My name is {name} and I'm really {adjective}.", **{"name": "Mark"})
Out[1]: "My name is Mark and I'm really {adjective}."
```

This can be specialized easily to do what the OP wanted:

```py
def f_blank(s, **kwargs):
    """Replaces missing keys with a blank."""
    try:
        return s.format(**kwargs)
    except KeyError as e:
        keyname = e.args[0]
        return f(s, **{ keyname: "" }, **kwargs)
```

I had a bit more fun with this idea:
https://gist.github.com/jlumbroso/57951c06a233c788e00d0fc309a93f91

```py
# (not a real import! just saying importing the code from the Gist)
from gist.57951c06a233c788e00d0fc309a93f91 import _make_f

# Define replacement f"..." compatible with Python 2 and 3
_f = _make_f(globals=lambda: globals(), locals=lambda: locals())

# Use:
s = "Test"
var = 1
assert _f("{s} {var}") == "Test 1"

# Inside a non-global scope, you may have to provide locals
def test():
    l_s = "Test"
    l_var = 1
    assert _f("{l_s} {l_var} / {s} {var}") == "{l_s} {l_var} / Test 1"
    assert _f("{l_s} {l_var} / {s} {var}", **locals()) == "Test 1 / Test 1"
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are still on Python 2, you can use `defaultdict` with `string.Formatter` to achieve this:

```
>>> format_string = '{foo:<2s}{bar:<3s}'
>>> data = {'bar': 'baz'}
>>> string.Formatter().vformat(format_string, (), defaultdict(str, data))
'  baz'
```

Answer (score 0):

Other solutions have one or more of the following characteristics, which won't work for my needs:
* don't support compound / nested names
* require python 3
* don't work
* don't give control over hierarchical default names in the case of a missing key

So here's a solution that addresses these issues. Note that this solution only works for text names e.g. "{key}" or "{nested[key]}". Not sure it will work for more than that e.g. "{foo:<2s}".

This also doesn't handle arrays, but could easily be extended to do so. You could also substitute your own function to output whatever placeholder result for missing values you wanted.

Usage examples:

```
my_data = {
    'hi': 'there',
    'abc': {
        'def': 'ghi'
    },
    'level1': {
        'level2': {
            'level3': 'nested'
        }
    }
}

s = "{hi} there"
print FormatDict(my_data).format(s) # 'there there'

s = "{hi} there {abc[def]}"
print FormatDict(my_data).format(s) # 'there there ghi'

s = "{hix} there {abc[def]}"
print FormatDict(my_data).format(s) # '{hix} there ghi'

s = "{hix} there {abc[defx]}"
print FormatDict(my_data).format(s) # '{hix} there {abc[defx]}'

s = "{hi} there {level1[level2][level3]}"
print FormatDict(my_data).format(s) # 'there there nested'

s = "{hix} there {level1[level2][level3x]}"
print FormatDict(my_data).format(s) # '{hix} there {level1[level2][level3x]}'
```

Here's the code:

```
import string

class FormatDict(dict):
    def set_parent(self, parent):
        self.parent = parent

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.parent = None
        self.last_get = ''
        for arg in (args or []):
            if isinstance(arg, dict):
                for k in arg:
                    self.__setitem__(k, arg[k])
        for k in (kwargs or {}):
            self.__setitem__(k, kwargs[k])

    def __getitem__(self, k):
        self.last_get = k
        try:
            val = dict.__getitem__(self, k)
            return val
        except:
            ancestry = [k]
            x = self.parent
            while x:
                ancestry.append(x.last_get)
                x = x.parent
            ancestry.reverse()
            return '{' + ancestry[0] + ''.join(['[' + x + ']' for x in ancestry[1:]]) + '}'

    def __setitem__(self, k, v):
        if isinstance(v, dict):
            v = FormatDict(v)
            v.set_parent(self)
        dict.__setitem__(self, k, v)

    def format(self, s):
        return string.Formatter().vformat(s, (), self)
```

Answer (score -1):

A way to avoid the key error is to include in the dict but leave it blank:

```
kwargs = {"name": "mark", "adjective": ""}
"My name is {name} and I'm really {adjective}.".format(**kwargs)
```

Keyword arguments expect their to be a key in kwargs. Another way to do it would be positional arguments:

```
"My name is {0} and I'm really {1}.".format("mark")
```

Prints "My name is Mark and I'm really." While

```
"My name is {0} and I'm really {1}.".format("mark","black")
```

Prints "My name is Mark and I'm really black."

Alternatively, you can catch the ValueError.

Comment: In my particular case, this solution won't work. I intend to populate the values that I'm going to end up using. I'm just trying to protect myself so that if I (or someone else) ends up putting in a field and forgets to put it into the dict, we don't just throw an exception and give up on the whole string.

Comment: Well, you should be catching errors anyway. You can also do an `assert` ahead of time to make sure adjective is atleast initialized to blank in the dictionary.

Comment: The solution above me by @Rob is the same as mine only more verbose: obviously update adjective later if the value is found

Comment: No, I don't statically know what string will be called format on (and with what kwargs). That's the whole problem. I *am* catching the exception (which is why it doesn't crash the whole application), but I don't want to fail completely when I could get a partially-filled out string instead.