# Python replace, using patterns in array

Tags: python, arrays, regex, replace

I need to replace some things in a string using an array, they can look like this:

```
array = [3, "$x" , "$y", "$hi_buddy"]
#the first number is number of things in array
string = "$xena is here $x and $y."
```

I've got another array with things to replace those things, let's say its called rep_array.

```
rep_array = [3, "A", "B", "C"]
```

For the replacement I use this:

```
for x in range (1, array[0] + 1):
  string = string.replace(array[x], rep_array[x])
```

But the result is:

```
string = "Aena is here A and B."
```

But I need to much only lonely $x not $x in another word.
Result should look like this:

```
string = "$xena is here A and B."
```

Note that:

- all patterns in `array` start with `$`.
- a pattern matches if it matches the whole word after `$`; `$xena` doesn't match `$x`, but `foo$x` *would* match.
- `$` can be escaped with `@` and than it should not be matched (for example `$x` does not match `@$x`)

Comment: Do all your replacement patterns start with `$`?

Comment: why don't you use [string formats](http://ebeab.com/2012/10/10/python-string-format/) from python, instead of reinventing the wheel?

Comment: @MartijnPieters: What about ` \$x ` and in the replacement array you would have ` A `?

Comment: @npinti: sorry, I don't follow what you mean there.

Comment: You could use a pattern like `r'\$x\b'` to replace only the `$x` which is not followed by a more characters (i. e. `$x` in `$x and $y` but not in `$xena`).  If things like `bla$x foo` also should not be replaced, then you could use sth like `r'((?P<=\W)|^)\$x\b'` for matching only this.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: Never mind :).

Comment: @npinti, with your approach you would not replace `$x` at the beginning of the string.

Comment: @Alfe: This is why I asked if the pattern always starts with `$`.

Comment: All of them starts with $

Comment: @MartijnPieters: Ok thanks. Removing my comments :).

Comment: + I can't really change the arrays itself, because it's a part of massive program.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a regular expression that wraps your source text with some whitespace look-behind and a `\b` anchor; make sure to include the start of the string too:

```
import re

for pattern, replacement in zip(array[1:], rep_array[1:]):
    pattern = r'{}\b'.format(re.escape(pattern))
    string = re.sub(pattern, replacement, string)
```

This uses `re.escape()` to ensure any regular expression meta characters in the pattern are escaped first. `zip()` is used to pair up your patterns and replacement values; a more pythonic alternative to your `range()` loop.

`\b` only matches at a position where a word character is followed by a non-word character (or vice versa), a *word boundary*. Your patterns all end in a word character, so this makes sure your patterns only match if the *next* character is not a word character, blocking `$x` from matching inside `$xena`.

Demo:

```
>>> import re
>>> array = [3, "$x" , "$y", "$hi_buddy"]
>>> rep_array = [3, "A", "B", "C"]
>>> string = "$xena is here $x and $y. foo$x matches too!"
>>> for pattern, replacement in zip(array[1:], rep_array[1:]):
...     pattern = r'{}\b'.format(re.escape(pattern))
...     string = re.sub(pattern, replacement, string)
... 
>>> print string
$xena is here A and B. fooA matches too!
```

Comment: Your solution is almost working the way I need, I also need to be able to escape the $ with @, can u tell me what's wrong with this patter?
pattern = r'(?:([^@])|^){}\b'.format(re.escape(pattern))

Comment: @Whitedracke: You need a look-behind: `r'(?:(?<=[^@])|^){}\b'`

Comment: @Whitedracke: or better still, a negative look-behind: `r'(?<!@){}\b'`

Answer (score 5):

this is not a direct answer to your question, but as I guess you'll get other solutions hacking around `\b`, I'm going to suggest you a more pythonic solution:

```
rep_dict = {'x': 'A', 'y': 'B', 'hi_buddy': 'C'}
string = '{xena} is here {x} and {y}'

print string.format(rep_dict)
```

but here, it will raise a `KeyError` for missing xena in `rep_dict`, which can be solved by [answers to that question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19799609), using a `defaultdict` or a formatter you may prefer depending on your use case.

The problem with using `$`, is that it is not trivial to make something that matches that does not define the real boundary. Most languages using `$` variables apply it to the next one character, using a boundary on larger characters (those are shells and makefiles), i.e. `${xena}`. Languages like Perl use a grammar to define the context of a `$` variable, and I guess they may use regexps as well in the tokenizer.

That's why in python, we only use formatting operators to mark the boundaries of the variable `{}` in the string, not having useless `$` so we do not have to deal with ambiguities (`$xena => ${x}ena or ${xena}?`).

HTH

Comment: of course, I'm giving this for the OP to know and consider using that if it can be an option to him, and for future readers that may consider using a `$` variable in strings for a use case that strings formats have been built for. ;-)

Comment: This is the correct TOOWTDI (https://wiki.python.org/moin/TOOWTDI), if the OP has any power over the input strings.

Answer (score 0):

`string.replace` does not know about regular expressions, so you have to use the `re` module (https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/re.html), namely the `re.sub` method:

```
>>>re.sub(r"\$x\b", "replace", r"$xenia $x")
'$xenia replace'
```

Comment: This'll match `$x` in `foo$x` too.

Comment: I need foo$x to be replaced, but dunno how the escape '\' get into the arrays.

Comment: @Whitedracke: That's an important detail; *do* include that in your question post!

Comment: @Whitedracke: I updated your post to include that detail, as well as the fact that all patterns start with `$`. It's details like that that make a *huge* difference in what is a proper solution and what is not.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try something like this:

```
import re

search = ["$x" , "$y", "$hi_buddy"]
replace = ["A", "B", "C"]
string = "$xena is here $x and $y skip$x."

repl = dict(zip(search, replace))
print re.sub(r'\B\$\w+', lambda m: repl.get(m.group(0), m.group(0)), string)

# result: $xena is here A and B skip$x.
```

`\B` here means "match $ when it's preceded by a non-word char". If you need `skip$x` to be replaced as well, just drop the `\B`:

```
print re.sub(r'\$\w+', lambda m: repl.get(m.group(0), m.group(0)), string)
# $xena is here A and B skipA.
```

Comment: Using `\B` means `$$x` is also matched.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: right, and so do `!$x`, `...$x` and similar. I didn't understand from the question if this is a desired behavior or not.