# Is there a way to format one string multiple times in Python?

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, string-formatting

I have a string like this:

```
my_string = '{general_setting} ... {specific_setting}'
```

The general_setting is the same for the whole program (i.e. database password), whereas the specific_setting can vary throughout the program. Is there a way to format one string twice, first inserting the general_setting and then having a pre-prepared string to insert the specific_setting later?

I'm sure this must have been asked before, but all I could find were questions about how to insert the same VALUE multiple times, not about how to insert different values at different times.

Comment: can you provide a [mcve]?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can have any level of formatting depending on the number of braces

```
>>> template = '{general_setting} ... {{specific_setting}}'.format(general_setting='general')
>>> my_string = template.format(specific_setting='specific')
>>> print (my_string)
general ... specific
```

Answer (score 8):

Alternatively, you can use the solution proposed in [python format string unused named arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17215400/python-format-string-unused-named-arguments):

```
class SafeDict(dict):
    def __missing__(self, key):
        return '{' + key + '}'
```

then:

```
>>> '{bond}, {james} {bond}'.format_map(SafeDict(bond='bond'))
```

returns:

```
'bond, {james} bond'
```

Answer (score 4):

Some additions to @[Sunitha](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3316882/sunitha) answer, the first time formatting is `{}`, second is `{{}}`, the third time is not `{{{}}}`, but it is `{{{{}}}}`.

**Four curly braces**, because every time you format, the curly braces will be reduced for every place.