# How to find where python's string.format(**kwargs) fails?

Tags: python, string, format

I have a long string with many formatting braces and many double braces that are not for format. I also have a dictionary with all the values to be used for formatting. Short example:

```py
text = """There are {n_cats:} cats and {n_dogs:} dogs.
A total of {7}.
Except that there is some {{normal text}}.
"""

kwargs = {'n_cats': 3, 'n_dogs': 4}

print(text.format(**kwargs))
```

This results in:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    print(text.format(**kwargs))
IndexError: tuple index out of range
```

And obviously one can see that instead of `{7}` there should be either `7` or `{{7}}`. But my real text is much much longer. Is there a way to easily find the place where `format()` breaks?

Comment: `{7}` is going to get the 7th positional argument. You gave 0.

Comment: @KlausD. It's also stated in the question. The problem is not why the error occurs.

Comment: You won't see more with the CPython iterpreter. IPython gives a little more info: `IndexError: Replacement index 7 out of range for positional args tuple`

Comment: Maybe you can search for problematic parts with regex. `re.search(r"\{\d+\}", text)` will give you `<re.Match object; span=(56, 59), match='{7}'>`

Comment: This gets to an issue of maintainability. If you have a single "line" that can fail in non-obvious ways, you should probably break it up into multiple lines, at least until you can piece it back together into a more robust single line.

Comment: @KlausD. thanks now I understand why a good ide helps !

Comment: Could You subclass Formatter ? in such a wy that printds the index raising the error ?? I don't know how to do it but after readibg this maybe ia a way to go for :https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17215400/format-string-unused-named-arguments/17215533#17215533 third answer

Comment: @Asocia This is helpful, but the patern would need to be extended as it also finds `{{7}}`. I'll combine it with my answer below. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks guys. The comments by @Asocia and @chepner gave me the idea which identifies the line in which the problem occurs. We can divide `text` into lines and apply format to each one of them (having too many keys in `kwargs` is not a problem). Code:

```py
try:
    print(text.format(**kwargs))
except Exception:
    for (i, t) in enumerate(text.split("\n")):
        try:
            t.format(**kwargs)
        except Exception:
            raise ValueError("Failed in line {:}".format(i+1))
```